# CSS - How to scale up images with homothety and limits?

Tags: css, image

I have a list of logos in a flex wrapper:

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed red;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 150px;
  max-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <!-- this one is well-sized (100x100) -->
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <!-- this one is too small on x axis (should be 150x60) -->
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x40" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <!-- this one is too small on y axis (should be 55x100) -->
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x90" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <!-- this one is too small on both axis (should be 150x100) -->
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/125x83" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

I want every logo to fill as much space as possible in a limit of 150x100px.

I can't use `object-fit: contain` as it would force every `<img>` to be 150x100px, and I don't want images to occupy the same space.

I would like to achieve something like this:

[image]

Where each logo is never wider than 150px and taller than 100px.

So I've put `max-width: 150px` and `max-height: 100px` on the images, but that's not enough.

Because some images are smaller than the display size.

The client can upload any image, and sometimes he can upload a 50x50px image, when the minimum size is 150x100px.

I don't care if the loaded images are smaller than the display size, I want to force their display's width and height.

But if I force it with `width: 100%` and `height: 100%`, it will force every image to always be 150x100px:

[image]

Is there a way to make every image scale as much as possible in order to occupy a space of 150x100px, no matter their intrinsic size?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do the wanted result just with the current html, but I've found a hack that uses the svg homothetic scaling capability:

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  gap: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed red;
}

li {
  position: relative;
  list-style-type: none;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

svg {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 150px;
  max-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200" />
    <svg width="1000" height="1000"></svg>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x40" />
    <svg width="1000" height="400"></svg>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x90" />
    <svg width="500" height="900"></svg>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/125x83" />
    <svg width="1250" height="830"></svg>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The trick here is to add an `<svg>` that has a width and height proportional to the image intrinsic size and greater than the display size (here, I've just multiplied the width and height by ten).

Then we reset the display width and height of the svg with `width: auto` and `height: auto` and we contain it with `max-width: 150px` and `max-height: 100px`.

Now the svgs have the good size.

To finish, we take the images out of the flow with `position: absolute` and we scale them to 100% of the parent `<li>` (which take the svg size).